# Add sip calling (TeleService) to AOSP on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I am trying to add sip calling capabilities to the generic aosp_x86_64-eng image.

I have downloaded, built and run on the emulator the AOSP image called aosp_x86_64-eng image. This works fine. Now I would like to add sip calling capabilities to it, mainly by plugging in the TeleService provided within the AOSP (found at packages/services/Telephony).

What I have tried:

1. Added only a few packages to aosp_x86_64.mk:

   PRODUCT_PACKAGES += 
   Telecom 
   TelephonyProvider 
   TeleService

- rebuilt & booted the image. No change observed (i.e. I couldn't find the sip options anywhere)

2. Added product="emulator" to all .xml resource files in TeleService. Also using change at prev point.

- rebuilt & booted the image. No change observed (i.e. I couldn't find the sip options anywhere)

3. Inherited from aosp_base_telephony.mk without change at point 1:

   $(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/aosp_base_telephony.mk)

- couldn't build an image:

  FAILED:
  build/make/core/main.mk:1204: warning:  build/make/target/product/aosp_x86_64.mk produces files inside build/make/target/product/mainline_system.mks artifact path requirement.
  Offending entries:
  system/etc/apns-conf.xml
  system/etc/sysconfig/preinstalled-packages-platform-full-base.xml
  build/make/core/main.mk:1204: error: Build failed.
  22:15:01 ckati failed with: exit status 1

4. Inherited from telephony.mk:

   $(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/telephony.mk)

- rebuilt & booted the image. No change observed (i.e. I couldn't find the sip options anywhere)

I find it very difficult to understand the build system and why I can't observe any change even if I add packages to the images. I admit that this trial and error way of developing is bad, but I didn't find any relevant documentation on how to add packages that are already available to an emulator image.

Answer (score 0):

> SIP runs over a wireless data connection, so your device must have a
> data connection (with a mobile data service or Wi-Fi). This means that
> you can't test on AVD—you can only test on a physical device. For
> details, see Testing SIP applications.

Taken from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip#requirements